# Lookup fields have id values even though parent object has been deleted - tips on fixing?

Tags: apex, soql, dml, isdeleted

In a sandbox org whenever I try to perform any DML on a `Product2` object I'm getting the generic invalid cross reference key error even if I'm only supplying the id field.

```
16:59:05.12 (140169065)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[1]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 01t*********; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

After some digging I noticed that a lookup field has a value for a deleted parent. For example the following fails the last assertion.

```
Id productId = '01t*********';
Product2 p = [select Product_Group__c from product2 where id = :productId];
system.assertNotEquals(null, p.Product_Group__c);
List<Product_Group__c> pg = [select id from Product_Group__c where id = :p.Product_Group__c];
System.assert(!pf.isEmpty()); // assertion fails
```

Challenge is I'm not able to clear the value so I can get back to doing my actual work. I've tried clearing the organization recycle bin, manually clearing these values, turning off triggers and workflows. But I still keep getting errors.

So with that background does the community know

- is this expected behavior or a bug?
- is there any trick to clearing these values?
- is there any script I need to ask salesforce support to run to clear this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this expected behavior or a bug?

If you're using a [Template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5) when creating or refreshing a Sandbox, it can leave orphaned Id values in lookup fields when copying; last I checked, this was an expected behavior. This will definitely cause the situation you've described. There are no other known situations where this should happen. If it does, report it as a bug.

> is there any trick to clearing these values?

You'll need to clear those fields out "manually." I guess you could write an Apex script to do this, or you could find them with the Data Loader, etc, but I don't know of a "automagical" fix out of the box.

> is there any script I need to ask salesforce support to run to clear this?

If they have a script, I'd love to know about it, just from an academic standpoint. I guess a well-designed batchable class could do it, but I don't have a good way to test it (I don't have access to Sandboxes where I can create this scenario).

###### Original Poster Replies

- No sandbox template, but same principle. Product2 data comes over with all sandbox copies and the parent record didn't.
- Was able to figure out a query to identify `SELECT Parent__c FROM Product2 WHERE Parent__c != NULL AND Parent__c NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Parent__c)` and cleared manually
- In my case I had to disable a number of triggers that were trying to use the old values for updates

Comment: the script thought came from when salesforce had to manually purge some deleted records from non-standard tables (i.e. AsyncApexJob table had entries blocking deployments even though they'd been "aborted" from the end user perspective)

Comment: @RalphCallaway Yeah, I remember having that problem too, now that you've mentioned it, but it's been like 7-8 years or something like that since I've had a need to use Sandboxes. Fortunately, Scratch Orgs are now my mainstay, so I don't have to worry about such nonsense.

Comment: man, I'm jealous. Scratch orgs are awesome, but I'm mostly working on 10+ yr old orgs and pulling anything out into dependencies is pretty much impossible ...